# Set the Parameter property of layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In a `BlazorWebAssembly` project I have a layout component which accepts the following parameter but I don't know how to set the parameter in app.razor since you have to set only the type of layout:

**Mylayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
  <div>
            @SideNavMenuItems
  </div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment SideNavMenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my **app.razor** :

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
          
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Mylayout)">
                    <Authorizing>
                        <text> Authotizing ...</text>
                    </Authorizing>
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        <text></text>
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>

            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Mylayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>

        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just make a new component SideNavMenuItems.razor and then use that in the layout?

Comment: @Akinzekeel No, because the there are more than projects and Layout is part of the Theme project and has SideNavMenuItems property as mentioned in the question and there is SideNavMenuItems component in the main project that uses the Theme project

Comment: As far as I know, A templated component is defined by specifying one or more component parameters of type RenderFragment or RenderFragment<TValue>. So, based on your description, I think you could create a Templated component with the SideNav, then use this component in the Mylayout.razor. More detail information, please check these links: [link 1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-templated-components-in-blazor/) and [link 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (you can also check the official sample).