# Set a separate layout for public users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor WebAssembly how to have separate layouts for logged-in users and users that are not logged-in?

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
               <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <Authorizing>
                        <text> Authotizing ...</text>
                    </Authorizing>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
          
           /*Something like this:*/
             <NotAuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(NotAuthorizedLayout)">
                    <Authorizing>
                        <text> Authotizing ...</text>
                    </Authorizing>
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        <text></text>
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </NotAuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>

            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>

        </NotFound>
        
    </Router>
```

or in another words how to switch between different layouts in Blazor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment doesn't exist a second parameter on `AuthorizeRouteView` to set a specific layout for 'public' users. But exists an easy solution, this is how you can deal easily with this scenario.

Let's suppose do you have 2 layouts ready to apply for auth and pub users:

- `AuthL.razor` for auth users.
- `PubL.razor` for public users.

At this moment, you can rewrite your `MainLayout.razor` using [AuthorizeView component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorizeview-component) to set the proper layout:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <AuthL Body=@Body />            
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <PubL Body=@Body />            
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

That's all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please answer this too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979561/set-the-parameter-property-of-layout

Comment: Hi @nAviD, I can't. The question doesn't have all needed details to write an answer.